# Restarting app after crash is not working

Tags: android, crash, restart

I need to restart my application after the crash occurs. My code below is not working. Am I missing anything?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyApplication implements java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private final Context myContext;

    public MyApplication(Context context) {
        myContext = context;
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myContext.startActivity(intent);

        System.exit(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that you are doing. If its a crash there is a reason and the stacktrace indicates the same which should be fixed before running again and this    `System.exit(10);` i not needed

Comment: yeah..i understood..but i just need to know how to start activity from   a crash..my program contains long process so i dont want to things stop my app..

Comment: no you can't do that. fix the crash and re-run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm telling you how you can `simulate` a restart, but you really, really **SHOULDN'T** be doing that!

```
    Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class);
    int mPendingIntentId = 123453456;
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(),
            mPendingIntentId, mStartActivity,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
            Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100,
            mPendingIntent);
    System.exit(0);
```

Again, you should find a cleaner solution.

Comment: should i need to add anything in main activity??